# Magento Error Call to a member function setCollection() on a non-object

Tags: magento, wamp, magento-1.4

I have a problem with my Magento. When I login and view my orders page, the following error is shown:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setCollection() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\danfemall\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Block\Order\History.php on line 58

When I remove the `setCollection` function from the code, it runs well but I wonder what the `setCollection` function does and is it wise to remove that function from the code.

Please someone help me out.

Comment: Has the file been changed in any other way previously? When I check the source line 58 is empty and line 60 has `setCollection` suggesting something is missing from your file.

Answer (score 0):

Magento version numbers always help when debugging Mangeto problems.  Also, where does android (your tag) fit in?

Assuming the following line is the one that's causing you trouble on your system

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'sales.order.history.pager')
    ->setCollection($this->getOrders());
```

Magento is trying to create a `page/html_pager` block object (which, assuming no overrides are in place, corresponds to a Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager).

In a working system, that's done with the following call.

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'sales.order.history.pager')
```

which returns the Block object, and then the setCollection method of the Block is called

```
->setCollection($this->getOrders());
```

However, in your system, the createBlock method isn't returning an object, and my guess is it's returning a boolean.  Take a look at the start of the Layout class's createBlock method.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
public function createBlock($type, $name='', array $attributes = array())
{
    try {
        $block = $this->_getBlockInstance($type, $attributes);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        return false;
    }
```

So, your system's been altered or is configured in such a way that attempts to create the `page/html_pager` block are throwing an exception.  Check your Magento exception log to see what kind of errors are being logged, or just temporarily drop in a `var_dump`

```
try {
    $block = $this->_getBlockInstance($type, $attributes);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage()); //don't forget to remove me before pushing 
                                //to production
    Mage::logException($e);
    return false;
}
```

As far as what this code does and how it will affect your system, the `setCollection` method adds a collection object (an array like object of models) to your Block object.  Without a collection, your pager block will (most likely) not render correctly.